# Octave fzero not a valid initial bracketing

Tags: loops, octave

**Why this for loop gives error: fzero: not a valid initial bracketing**

Code:

```
a = input('Introduza o valor de a: ');
x = 0:.1:50;
h = @(x) cos(x);
g = @(x) exp(a*x)-1;
f = @(x) h(x) - g(x);

c = zeros(length(x))
for i=1:length(x)
    c(i) = fzero(f,x(i));
end

plot(x, f(x));
hold on
plot(c,f(c),'-xr')
hold off
```

Comment: What's `a`? Which value of `i` does this error occur at? And I think you want `c = zeros(length(x),1);`.

Comment: value of a is asked in an input. Made edit to include.

Comment: That's not very helpful. What is the actual value of `a` you input when you run the code. And print out `i` in your `for` loop to determine when the error occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works perfectly in Matlab R2015b. I'm guessing that Octave's [`fzero`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/fzero.html) uses a different routine to find a bracket for a root when only a single initial guess is supplied (or you're using an old version of Octave/`fzero` that doesn't support the single value option).

You could try supplying your own function to find a valid bracket from a single initial guess. See this [recent post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/11/09/zeroin-part-3-matlab-zero-finder-fzero/) by MathWorks founder Cleve Moler and, in particular, the example `signchange` function. Create an M-file (or a sub-function) on your path of the `signchange` function and then try:

```
x = 0:0.1:50;
h = @(x) cos(x);
g = @(x) exp(a*x)-1;
f = @(x) h(x) - g(x);

c = zeros(length(x),1)
for i=1:length(x)
    [a,b] = signchange(f,x(i))
    c(i) = fzero(f,[a b]);
end

plot(x, f(x));
hold on
plot(c,f(c),'-xr')
hold off
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, but i manage to keep it working without using the signchange aproach. I wiil keep your answer for future use :)